# Objects empty after code refactoring

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why the following code produces different outputs:

First algorithm:

```
var data = {
    l1: 1,
    l2: 2,
    l3: 3
};
var datas = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    datas[i] = {}
    for (key in data) {
        datas[i][key] = data[key]
    }
};
delete datas[0].l1
delete datas[1].l2
delete datas[2].l3
console.log(data)
console.log("%j", datas)
```

Output:

```
{ l1: 1, l2: 2, l3: 3 }
[{"l2":2,"l3":3},{"l1":1,"l3":3},{"l1":1,"l2":2}]
```

Second algorithm:

```
var data = {
    l1: 1,
    l2: 2,
    l3: 3
};
var datas = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    datas[i] = {}
    datas[i] = data ; 
};
delete datas[0].l1
delete datas[1].l2
delete datas[2].l3
console.log(data)
console.log("%j", datas)
```

Output:

```
{}
[{},{},{}]
```

Comment: second example you are deleting l1, l2 and l3 from datas, which also means deleting the ones from data as they point to the same reference

Comment: how i create a object from data , not a reference , without using the first methode !!

Comment: @Avinash :
Down in the node.js source, the %j placeholder results in a call to JSON.stringify() on the passed argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following line from your second block/Algo:

```
datas[i]=data
```

you are just defining another reference to the same object `data` (and not new objects). So, after you delete all properties from this `data` object, those references reflect that change.

Comment: how i  create a object from data , not a reference !

Answer (score 1):

Using Lodash (it will create object, not reference):

```
var data = {
    l1: 1,
    l2: 2,
    l3: 3 
}; 
var datas = _.map(data,function(v,k){
    return _.omit(data,k); 
});
```